# Unit Testing of methods define inside a class using doctesting

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

I need to define:
1. doctests for '**init**' which creates a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5 and checks that accessing attribute 'radius' return 2.5.
2. Define a doc test for 'area' which creates a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5 and checks that it computed area is 19.63.

I have written below mentioned code but not getting the output.
Please suggest.

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius):

        """
        >>> c1=Circle(2.5).__init__()
        2.5
        """
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):

        """
        >>> c1=Circle(2.5).area()
        19.63

        """

        return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2),2)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how your class with doctests can be probably written:

```
import math

class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius):

        """
        >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
        >>> c1.radius
        2.5
        """
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):

        """
        >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
        >>> c1.area()
        19.63

        """

        return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2),2)
```

And this is how you should run `doctest` to get detailed output:

```
$ python -m doctest -v file.py
Trying:
    c1 = Circle(2.5)
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    c1.radius
Expecting:
    2.5
ok
Trying:
    c1 = Circle(2.5)
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    c1.area()
Expecting:
    19.63
ok
2 items had no tests:
    file
    file.Circle
2 items passed all tests:
   2 tests in file.Circle.__init__
   2 tests in file.Circle.area
4 tests in 4 items.
4 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Answer (score 2):

`__init__()` does not return the radius, rather the `Circle` object you created.
If you update the doctest to something like

```
>>> Circle(2.5).radius
2.5
```

it should work. Also note that you should not call `__init__()` directly, that's what `Circle(2.5)` does. In your case you should get an error, since you're not passing the right amount of arguments.

Comment: are you suggesting something like this:  >>> c1=Circle(2.5)
        >>> c1.radius
        2.5

Comment: You may want to mention in your answer that assignment expressions do not return the value that is named.